# How to clone the collect feedback workflow to customize it?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

It is possible to add the "Collect feedback" workflow to a document library. I would like to clone this workflow and make some customazation. Is this possible? Maybe in SharePoint designer?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from the SharePoint designer. Feedback workflow is a reusable workflow and I think you can clone. I haven`t tested this but my experience on other workflows I am giving steps followed

1. Open your site from the SharePoint designer.
2. Copy, and Paste Feedback workflow and rename the new one.
3. Edit your workflow and make required changes.

or you can do below steps for a new one as there is only one step in that workflow

1. Create a SharePoint 2010 reusable workflow
2. Add an action "Start Feedback Process" and do whatever you want as per your requirement.